# How to write bluetooth data into apple health kit in iOS swift

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth

I have data from third party devices using bluetooth blood pressure, blood sugar and I want to send these data to the apple health i.e.write the data into apple health can any one please provide example using swift 5.

Answer (score 0):

You collect your BLE data, extract the value and then use a simple save function in HealthKitStore. (Be sure to provide writing permissions during authorization first!).

Here is a sample function for blood glucose.

```
func writeBloodGlucose(value: Double, measurementDate: Date) throws {
    let healthStore = HKHealthStore()
    let bloodSugar = HKQuantitySample(
        type: HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .bloodGlucose)!,
        quantity: HKQuantity(
            unit: HKUnit.gramUnit(with: .milli).unitDivided(by: HKUnit.liter()),
            doubleValue: value
        ),
        start: measurementDate,
        end: measurementDate,
        device: HKDevice(
            name: "name",
            manufacturer: "manufacturer",
            model: "model",
            hardwareVersion: "hardwareVersion",
            firmwareVersion: "firmwareVersion",
            softwareVersion: "softwareVersion",
            localIdentifier: "localIdentifier",
            udiDeviceIdentifier: "udiDeviceIdentifier"
        ),
        metadata: nil)
    healthStore.save(bloodSugar) { (success, error) in
        print(success)
        print(error)
    }
}
```

If you want, I have developed a CocoaPod which simplifies the writing/reading data from AppleHealth. Here is the link: https://cocoapods.org/pods/HealthKitReporter